# strange code in ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker

Tags: java, multithreading

I have found such strange code in ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask

```
if (runState < STOP && Thread.interrupted() && runState >= STOP)
                thread.interrupt();
```

Why does it need to check `runState < STOP` and `runState >= STOP`.
There is a comment that explains in some way why such double check is necessary but I dont understand it.

So to compute final value of expression it will take from memory runState, then call Thread.interrupted() and then again take from memory runState (the first runState may differ from the second?) and combine these three expression's values with and?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial purpose of the code is to clear `interrupted` state of the thread unless it's `shuttingDownNow`, so it had to be just

```
if (runState < STOP)
      Thread.interrupted();
```

But we have concurrency. Consider two threads running code, `Worker`:

```
if (runState < STOP &&
      Thread.interrupted() &&
      runState >= STOP)
    thread.interrupt();
```

and thread executing `shutdownNow`:

```
if (state < STOP)
    runState = STOP;
for (Worker w : workers) {
    w.interruptNow();
}
```

Now here is the case for this double check

```
Worker:        if (runState < STOP &&    // true for now

shutdownNow:   if (state < STOP)
shutdownNow:       runState = STOP;      // set new state
shutdownNow:   for (Worker w : workers) {
shutdownNow:       w.interruptNow();     // interrupt      
shutdownNow:   }

Worker:              Thread.interrupted() &&   // clears interrupted state 
Worker:              runState >= STOP)         // but we have double check
Worker:            thread.interrupt();         // that will setup it again
```